# nodejs callback: doesn't detect any errors, just like if there were no error at all

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node js/Javascript doesn't catch the error while querying mysql server

The nodejs server queries the `submittedName` from form, checks the database along with `submittedName`. If `submittedName` matches with the `submittedName`, renders `success`. If it doesn't match, it should render `notfound`. 
But indeed, it does not. Instead, it renders success. Even on wrong input.

```
app.post("/whatisyourname", (req, res) => {
  var submittedName = req.body.details;
  console.log(details);

  //query the mysql database
  conn.query(
    "SELECT * FROM giftapp where name= ?",
    submittedName,
    (err, rs) => {

      //handle the error

      if (err) {
        console.log(err);

        //while it should render the "notfound" file,
        //it renders "success"

        res.render("notfound");
      } else {
        //if no error, render success
        res.render("success", { myR: rs[0] });
      }
    }
  );
```

I expect to be forwarded to "notfound" in case of wrong input or just any error
And to be forwarded to "success" in case of correct input

Comment: res.send("not found") i think... if you don't have a "not found " view

Comment: the view is called "notfound.ejs"
But that's not the problem. In fact, it does not render "notfound" when an error is present.

Comment: @ambianBeing Thanks, I didn't know some kind of thing existed. I just realised it now. As Mohammed mentioned. Thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **express** server or **sql connection** or **callback** won't throw any error in this case. You will get an error if something goes wrong while querying the db, i.e Invalid query or connection error etc. In your case the query executes successfully and gives you the result which is an empty array. You need to manually check and return the result. Change your code like:

```
app.post("/whatisyourname", (req, res) => {
    const submittedName = req.body.details;
    console.log(details);

    //query the mysql database
    conn.query(
        "SELECT * FROM giftapp where name= ?",
        submittedName,
        (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.render("notfound");
            } else {
                if (results && results.length > 0) {
                    res.render("success", { myR: results[0] });
                } else {
                    res.render("notfound");
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var submittedName = req.body.details;

var sql = 'SELECT * FROM giftapp WHERE name = ?';
con.query(sql, [submittedName], function (err, result) {
  if (err) res.render("notfound"); // if you view is called notfound.ejs remove the space between not and found.
  console.log(result);
  res.render("success", { myR: result[0] }); // need success.ejs
});
```